# Looking for effective way to retrieve cts:element-values() count

Tags: marklogic

I need to test the number of entry of a specific lexicon (range index). I can do it using fn:count(cts:element-values()), but this will end up running too slowly with a large lexicon. Is there a better way to compute the total number of values ?

Note that I don't wan't the number of fragment as returned by cts:count-aggregate, but the number of values.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no better query. Maybe run once and cache the results for reuse.

You don’t say how slow it is. It shouldn’t take more than a few seconds usually if you’ve got the right cluster size.

Comment: You are right, In my case I don't need a precise result but only a trend. So relying on a cached value is good enough.
This can take up to 30 seconds to compute for certain index, but once cached, it will worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:  cts:count-aggregate($index-reference, 'item-frequency')